# Node js iss site not open in other computer

Tags: node.js, iis, deployment, windows-10

I have an node js express app for service module and angular app for web, which is deployed in the windows 10 iis server at the domains

"http://localhost:8011" and "http://localhost:8012"

If i test the site in my browser like 
"http://localhost:8011" and "http://localhost:8012"

or

"http://{port number}:8011" and "http://{port number}:8012" it's working

but if same thing i open in others computer the angular application is working without any issue.

but the node js is not working

it's giving the error like

> This site can’t be reached
>
> {port number} took too long to respond.

Can any one suggest me what is the error and how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say you test the browser on your computer. Do you test it with the same machine that runs the IIS server?

Comment: There can be many things blocking the connection. My guess is that you need to add a rule about ports 8011 and 8012 in your windows firewall

Comment: Thanks for the info, yes it's blocked by the firewall. It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear from the question but from what I understand you are trying to serve a node express app through IIS?

If this is the case, you should look at the [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/releases) package which is really helpful. You will also need to install the [IIS rewrite-rule module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) if this is not already installed.
If this is indeed what you are looking for let my know, and I will edit me answer to include more details.